# Correct way to set PATH variable within a Ubuntu docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, environment-variables

I have a container based on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed some custom stuff into `/opt/bin`.

Now I want to add `/opt/bin` to `$PATH`. However, no matter what I try, the path variable isn't available after the Docker container restarts.

So far I tried to add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin
```

to `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/myvars.sh`.

What is the proper way to add the path?

Comment: Check this answer out:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38742545/3781327

Comment: I need it without dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update *.bashrc* file in $HOME directory (*~/.bashrc*), not */etc/profile* or */etc/profile.d/myvars.sh*

```
export PATH: export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin
```

To set it permanently, and system wide (all users, all processes) set variable in /etc/environment

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin
```