# Not available variable in path of a Docker container

Tags: linux, bash, apache-spark, docker, spark-submit

I am trying to execute a tool (which requires `spark-submit` available in the path) inside a Docker container with Apache Spark (indeed to resolve this issue, in Dockerfile I added the instruction `RUN echo "export PATH=$PATH:/spark/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`).

If I connect to this Docker container (with the command `sudo docker exec -it $spark_masterID bash`, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505506/how-to-get-bash-or-ssh-into-a-running-container-in-background-mode)), the tool work without any problem and I can see the typical Spark output.

But in my case I am interested in calling this tool without connecting to the container, indeed I have a script in this container which calls the tool. In order to call it I use the command:

`sudo docker exec -it $spark_masterID bash /path/script.sh`

but this time the execution fails, reporting this error:
`Make sure spark-submit is available in your path`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: thanks @LuisMuñoz it worked for me (after some editing)! I understand your point jww so I should remove this question?