# How to set a custom npm directory for global packages in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I've just read the best practices about [Global npm dependencies](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/docs/BestPractices.md#global-npm-dependencies) and tried to utilize this approach in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon
...
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH="/home/node/.npm-global:${PATH}"
...
RUN npm install -g nodemon
...
CMD ["nodemon", "server.js"]
USER node
```

But when I try to start the container I get:

```
ERROR: for my_project_node_1  Cannot start service my_project_node:
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"nodemon\": 
executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for my_project_node  Cannot start service my_project_node: 
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"nodemon\": 
executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I just don't understand what I do incorrectly..

How to set PATH environment variable in a Dockerfile I get from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38742545/202550

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this as I couldnt find propper documentation on it, but do you need the PATH to be set? Does npm not sort it out using hte NPMCONFIG_PREFIX alone?

Comment: Nope, I tried without setting the PATH variable, the same result.