# Docker: Set export PATH in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have to set `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH`. As long I do it via `docker exec -it <container> bash` manually it works. However, I tried to automate it in my `.dockerfile` with:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
RUN conda install --yes -c conda-forge fbprophet
ENV PATH="~/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

And it seems like `ENV PATH="~/.local/bin:${PATH}"` is not having the same effect as I receive that WARNING here. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

```
WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-decrypt-bigfile, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-encrypt-bigfile, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/jovyan/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a Dockerfile, How to update PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make use of [ENV](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive in `dockerfile`

```
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/jovyan/.local/bin"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

`$PATH` is a list of actual directories, *e.g.*, `/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/dmaze/bin`.  No expansion ever happens while you're reading `$PATH`; if it contains `~/bin`, it looks for a directory named exactly `~`, like you might create with a shell `mkdir \~` command.

When you set `$PATH` in a shell, `PATH="~/bin:$PATH"`, first your local shell expands `~` to your home directory and then sets the environment variable.  **Docker does not expand `~` to anything**, so you wind up with a `$PATH` variable containing a literal `~`.

The best practice here is actually to avoid needing to set `$PATH` at all.  A Docker image is an isolated filesystem space, so you can install things into the "system" directories and not worry about confusing things maintained by the package manager or things installed by other users; the `Dockerfile` is the only thing that will install anything.

```sh
RUN pip install awscli
# without --user
```

But if you must set it, you need to use a Dockerfile `ENV` directive, and you need to specify absolute paths.  ([`$HOME` does seem to be well-defined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#env-environment-variables) but since Docker containers aren't usually multi-user, "home directory" isn't usually a concept.)

```sh
ENV PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

(In a Dockerfile, [Docker will replace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) `$VARIABLE`, `${VARIABLE}`, `${VARIABLE:-default}`, and `${VARIABLE:+isset}`, but it doesn't do any other shell expansion; path expansion of `~` isn't supported but variable expansion of `$HOME` is.)