# How to add cargo (or any executable) to path in Dockerfile for subsequent build steps?

Tags: docker

I have the following snippet in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
RUN USER=root cargo new --bin foobar
```

The problem is, the 2nd `RUN` fails because `cargo` is not in the path.

Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried setting the path like this (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable)):

```
ENV PATH $HOME/.cargo/.bin:$PATH
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Why not `FROM` one of the `rustlang/rust` images: https://hub.docker.com/_/rust. Then you've got Rust installed and you're off to the races!

Comment: I'm compiling on this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch to ensure the resulting rust binary doesn't have dynamic linking issues

Comment: Ah, OK. You may want to check the rustlang Dockerfile to see how they do it: https://github.com/rust-lang/docker-rust/blob/master/Dockerfile-debian.template

Comment: You have a typo in the path to cargo binary.

You wrote: `ENV PATH $HOME/.cargo/.bin:$PATH`
Should drop the last dot to `ENV PATH $HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

You can use --from with COPY command.

```
FROM rust:1.40 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
COPY . .
RUN cargo new --bin foobar

FROM another-image-that-you-want-to-use
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp
...
```