# Is it possible to pass environment variables from one RUN to another, in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm doing this:

```
RUN export FOO=hello
RUN env
```

The second `RUN` doesn't see the `FOO` environment variable. Is it a limitation of Docker?

If it is, how do I set `PATH` in one `RUN` and make it available in another `RUN`?

Comment: Each RUN statement runs in it's own shell, so environment variables aren't passed from RUN statement to RUN statement. If you can combine your statements into one RUN statement, then it'll work. I.e. `RUN export FOO=hello && env`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile: Bash export statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792050/dockerfile-bash-export-statement-not-working) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62624072/export-command-in-dockerfile-giving-error-in-docker-build ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker RUN command initializes its own shell when called in a new line. There is no connection between the two RUN commands.

Bash commands, however, can be combined in a single RUN statement.

```
RUN export FOO=hello \
    && env
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Dockerfile's `ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#env) instruction for this purpose?

Comment: In need to set `PATH` in one `RUN` and then make sure it's used in all following `RUN`'s

Comment: ARG and ENV will literally effect all subsequent RUN directives.