# Setting enviroment variable of the container through bash script is not working

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, sh

I'm trying to set a enviroment variable of a docker container through bash script.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c","source runservice.sh"]
```

runservice.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export "foo"="bar"
```

Now after pushing it when I go inside the container and do printenv, it is not setting up enviroment variable.
But if I run the same command inside the container, env variable is getting set up.
What's the correct way I can export using bash script?

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  (I'd expect a container with that `CMD` to exit immediately.)  I'd prefer the Dockerfile `ENV` directive if you can (also see [In a Dockerfile, How to update PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable)) , or else an entrypoint wrapper script.

Comment: Since there are some constraints , I can not use ENV directive.
docker stack deploy to start the container.

Comment: I also tried using Entrypoint but that too doesn't sets the env variable.
What am I missing?

Comment: That runs a shell, changes the environment of *that* shell, and then that shell exits. You can't modify your environment by running some other command.

Comment: Thanks for explaination.
Actually I'm trying to implement this: https://medium.com/@adrian.gheorghe.dev/using-docker-secrets-in-your-environment-variables-7a0609659aab and if you read the last point 'in your container entrypoint, call the following function for each environment variable you have set up.' .
Then what is the container entrypoint if we can not modify the env variable?
Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: `what is the container entrypoint` I'm sorry, did you try googling that?

Answer (score 0):

> it is not setting up enviroment variable

It's setting the environment for the duration of `CMD` build stage. Sure, it has no effect on anything else - the shell run at `CMD` stage is then exiting. See dockerfile documentation.

> What's the correct way I can export using bash script?

There is no correct way. The correct way to affect the environment, is to use `ENV`.

There is a workaround in contexts that use entrypoint - you can set entrypoint to a shell (or a custom process) that will first source the variables.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "source runservice.sh && \"$@\"", "--"]
```

Comment: I tried entrypoint to a shell, but still I'm not able to set enviroment