# exit status 127 when running ffmpeg from golang

Tags: docker, go, ffmpeg

Hi I am using the following docker image:

```
FROM golang:alpine3.18
```

With ffmpeg: (probably here I am missing something)

```
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
```

However when trying to execute the following:

```
cmd := "ffmpeg -i Untitled.mp4 -vf \"fps=5,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos\" -c:v pam -f image2pipe - | convert -delay 5 - -loop 0 -layers optimize test.gif"
_, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd).Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to execute command: %s", err))
}
```

I get this error:

```
  Failed to execute command: exit status 127
```

Comment: Is ffmpeg in your path?

Comment: @NickODell currently no , please advise on how to set ffmpeg in my path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable

Comment: Assign os.Stderr (or a *bytes.Buffer) to Cmd.Stderr to see any errors reported by bash. Alternatively, inspect [`err.(*exec.ExitError).Stderr`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#ExitError.Stderr) (which may be incomplete).

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are converting the output of **ffmpeg** into an animated gif with using **convert** command. You need to install **[ImageMagic](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)** in your containers for this to work.

> The convert command is a member of the ImageMagick suite of tools

Add this in your Docker file

```
RUN apk add --no-cache imagemagick
```

Reference :

- https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality