# Add path to default system $PATH in Docker

Tags: docker

I would like to create a Docker image with a Rust/cargo binary such that all users can use said binary. This successfully builds the image

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

RUN apt-get --yes install cargo
RUN cargo install oxipng
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.cargo/bin"
RUN oxipng --help
```

but when using it, `/root/.cargo/bin` is *not* in the path.

How can I add the path to the default system `$PATH`?

Comment: Are the quotes in the `ENV` line causing a problem?  Docker does not run a shell, and I might guess it's including the quotes as part of the variable value.  If you had a directory named `/root/.cargo/bin"` with the quote as part of the directory name, that might be the last `$PATH` component.

Comment: (It's possible the [`rust`](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) image will be easier to work with here.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a duplicate of [In a Dockerfile, How to update PATH environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093612/in-a-dockerfile-how-to-update-path-environment-variable) - you're doing it right, I tried it and the PATH contains `/root/.cargo/bin` in the PATH env